# GJs/Seed GtkSourceView

Tags: seed, gtksourceview, gjs

I can get a `Gtk.TextView` working with the following code—

```
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;
let mtext1 = new Gtk.TextView();
```

However, I would rather use a GtkSourceView, as it has line numbers. How can I do this? I can't find much documentation around the subject.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Import the GtkSource library:

```
const GtkSource = imports.gi.GtkSource;
let mtext1 = new GtkSource.View();
```